# Merge cells without actually merging them

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in Excel that contains some rows that need to be merged. The problem is, I need to keep functionality of a table (ex. **filtering**), which doesn't allow merging anyways.

I researched the topic, but couldn't find anything except for "Center Across Selection" option, which is not what I'm looking for. When I filter by a column in which the merge should take place, I want it to return all the rows, not just the first one (and center accross section doesn't work for rows, only columns).

Here's an example table:

[image: Table with cells that need to be merged marked in yellow]

I need to merge row 2 and 3 under columns "ID" and "Amount" (yellow cells).

One solution I came up with is to just copy the values from first row to the other rows. The problem is, I have an "Amount" column that needs to be summed at the end of the table. When I copy the values, the sum is greater than it should be, of course.

[image: Table with values copied over]

I can leave the amount only in the first row, but as I said, I want filter to work properly and return all rows that match.

How can I achieve this? I was thinking about writing an application, but that might be an overkill for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanatory comments under my original answer, this is a separate answer specific to the data usage in question. Adding a new IsPrimary column will enable you to use the `SUMIF` function, which is like the `SUM` function but can sum only values from the rows you specify.

[image]

In this case, you want to sum only the values from the primary row for each application, so the formula in cell E6 is:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B5,"=1",E2:E5)
```

As you can see, there are two ranges passed to the `SUMIF` function in this example, plus a condition "=1". Using this formula, Excel will examine the values in the range `B2:B5`, and where those cells meet the condition "=1", Excel will include such rows when summing the range `E2:E5`.

There is more information about `SUMIF` [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Comment: I thinks this is a proper solution. Thank you! I'll get back to you if my clients have any questions or concerns regarding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use Excel as both a database and a document formatter. Excel is very versatile and can do a lot for us in both these roles, but they do sometimes conflict and yours is just such an example.

Since you need Excel to hold your data such that you can manipulate it in rows and apply filtering and calculation, it would be better not to try and combine this with any formatting, merging of cells etc.

Rather than leaving blank cells or merging cells, try to define your data to include all the information needed in order to use formulae to achieve what you need.

For instance, using your knowledge of which rows contain a value that should be excluded from a summed total, you may include an additional column containing say a 1 or a 0 to mark the relevant rows. Then, you may refer to this additional column in your formulae to obtain the correct calculation.

Also, consider using the subtotal function in conjunction with the sum function where appropriate. Again you may wish to use one or more additional columns, to hold intermediate subtotal values that contribute to a grand total.

Comment: I think I should have left merging out of the question, as it's not what I really want to do. It was just a way of explaining my problem. Can you elaborate in which way I would use a subtotal? Thank you!

Comment: @BožoStojkovic I will try but you will need to explain more about the data. You have shown what you want to achieve, but not why. For instance, I can see that the row you want excluded from the total has the same ID as the row above, but it has different values for Address and Parts, so it's not obvious why it should be excluded. We need to understand the reason in order for the solution to continue to work correctly with filtering etc.

Comment: This table represents applications for funding. "ID" marks ID of application. Each application is for a single building. A building can have multiple entrances, hence multiple addresses. Also, each entrance marks a part of the building, which has several attributes. "Parts" is just a placeholder. Each application has a single amount for funding no matter how many entrances. Does that explain it somewhat?

Comment: Yes. I've added a new answer for this specific data usage.